# Php Repeatable region

Tags: php

So i got this code, at the moment it is repeating everything , and i just wanted it to repeat the echo, so i get all usernames from it, if i leave it as it is it will also repeat the form when i press a username. Every time i tried to ajust it, it just gave me syntax errors

```
<?php do { ?>
        <?php
                 $username = $row_mensagens['username'];
                 $user     = $row_mensagens['id'];

        if(isset($_GET['user']) && !empty($_GET['user'])){
          ?>

          <form>
            Introduz mensagem : <br>
            <textarea name='message' rows='7' cols='60'></textarea>
            <br><br>
            <input type='submit' value="Send Message" />
          </form>

          <?php
        } else {

                  echo "<p><a href='mensagens.php?user=$user'>$username</a></p>";


              }


        ?>
          <?php } while ($row_mensagens = mysql_fetch_assoc($mensagens)); ?>
```

Comment: So move `<form>` outside of loop and leave only that output, that you need to be repeated.

Answer (score 0):

that `do { } while()` will always repeat as many as the number of records come from database.

You can do it this way:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['user']) && !empty($_GET['user'])){
?>
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="user" value="<?php echo $_GET['user']; ?>" /> <!-- hidden field so you can process to who -->
    Introduz mensagem : <br>
    <textarea name='message' rows='7' cols='60'></textarea>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type='submit' value="Send Message" />
</form>

<?php
    } else {
        do {
            $username = $row_mensagens['username'];
            $user     = $row_mensagens['id'];
            echo "<p><a href='mensagens.php?user=$user'>$username</a></p>";
        } while ($row_mensagens = mysql_fetch_assoc($mensagens));
    }
?>
```

Move `do {` inside `else` and show the form only if you have a `$_GET['user']`

I have also added for you a hidden field, so you know who to send message.

Hope you understand how this works. [Documentation on `Control Structures: do-while`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php)

I also suggest to make that form a `post` form, as by default it is a `get` form, and since you have a `textarea` you are more likely to bump into errors if the message is too long.

LE: Another suggestion, try to move to [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) or [mysqli_* functions](http://php.net/mysqli_connect) since [mysql_* functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) are considered deprecated as of `PHP 5.5` and have some good chances to be removed.